# nvidia driver mismatch, nvidia-smi not working

Tags: drivers, nvidia, graphics

I was using pytorch and my gpu wasn't working, said there was a mismatch between kernel driver version and DSO version. Every tutorial online for the first error says to start with `nvidia-smi` but it outputs `NVIDIA-SMI has failed because it couldn’t communicate with the NVIDIA driver. Make sure that the latest NVIDIA driver is installed and running` I tried switching drivers back to xorg and then back to my usual nvidia 525 driver but that didn't work. I am on ubuntu 23.04 and have GeForce RTX 3050 Mobile.

Comment: Look in lsmod output for "nvidia", probably not there.  An update may break the nvidia module build if some nvidia packages are held back (phasing), try dropping back a kernel vesion (grub/advanced...). Does update/upgrade show nvidia packages held back?

Comment: [This guy](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1477897/nvidia-driver-stops-working-on-reboot-ubuntu-23-04-lunar) seems to have the same problem, maybe keep an eye on that for an answer.